# How to set Values for Reverb Effects in android?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, audioeffect

I am working on an app that has a reverb feature. I know we can achieve this feature by the PresetReverb and EnvironmentalReverb classes.

For customization, we have the EnvironmentalReverb class and I am using this class like this and effects can be notice in the video:

```
val eReverb = EnvironmentalReverb(1, simpleExoplayer?.audioSessionId!!)
            eReverb.reverbDelay = 5 // [0, 100] done
            eReverb.roomLevel = -1000 // [-9000, 0]
            eReverb.reverbLevel = 2000 // [-9000, 2000]
            eReverb.decayHFRatio = 1000.toShort()
            eReverb.decayTime = 10000
            eReverb.density = 1000.toShort()
            eReverb.diffusion = 1000.toShort()
            eReverb.enabled = true
            val auxEffectInfo = AuxEffectInfo(eReverb.id, 1.0F)
            simpleExoplayer?.setAuxEffectInfo(auxEffectInfo)
```

Problem: If we want to apply the EnvironmentalReverb values according to the PresetReverb class effects(LARGE_ROOM, LARGE_HALL, MEDIUM_ROOM, etc) then what should be the values of reverbDelay, diffusion, density, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [EnvironmentalReverb source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/media/java/android/media/audiofx/EnvironmentalReverb.java) refers to the [OpenSL ES 1.0.1 specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenSL-ES/specs/OpenSL_ES_Specification_1.0.1.pdf).

Pages 451-452 in that specification lists the following preset definitions:

```
#define SL_I3DL2_ENVIRONMENT_PRESET_SMALLROOM \
 { -1000,-600, 1100, 830, -400, 5, 500, 10, 1000, 1000 }
#define SL_I3DL2_ENVIRONMENT_PRESET_MEDIUMROOM \
 { -1000,-600, 1300, 830, -1000, 20, -200, 20, 1000, 1000 }
#define SL_I3DL2_ENVIRONMENT_PRESET_LARGEROOM \
 { -1000,-600, 1500, 830, -1600, 5, -1000, 40, 1000, 1000 }
#define SL_I3DL2_ENVIRONMENT_PRESET_MEDIUMHALL \
 { -1000,-600, 1800, 700, -1300, 15, -800, 30, 1000, 1000 }
#define SL_I3DL2_ENVIRONMENT_PRESET_LARGEHALL \
 { -1000,-600, 1800, 700, -2000, 30, -1400, 60, 1000, 1000 }
#define SL_I3DL2_ENVIRONMENT_PRESET_PLATE \
 { -1000,-200, 1300, 900, 0, 2, 0, 10, 1000, 750 }
```

The 10 values listed for each of the presets ought to correspond to the `EnvironmentalReverb` parameters in the following order: `PARAM_ROOM_LEVEL`, `PARAM_ROOM_HF_LEVEL`, `PARAM_DECAY_TIME`, `PARAM_DECAY_HF_RATIO`, `PARAM_REFLECTIONS_LEVEL`, `PARAM_REFLECTIONS_DELAY`, `PARAM_REVERB_LEVEL`, `PARAM_REVERB_DELAY`, `PARAM_DIFFUSION`, `PARAM_DENSITY`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Michael, I will try these values and share my results with you.

Comment: Hi Michael, I have tried the above effects in EnvironmentalReverb Preset but the effects are sounding very low, which means there is a very low difference between the original and applied effects video. 
Is there any idea why it is happening?